# Docker Compose Sql DB image connection error

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file and I want to create three containers to run my node app: a client, a server, a db container with some data.

I have troubles to create the db container and connect it to the server container, I'm using sequelize to connect with db, but on `docker-compose up` command I have connection error on server app startup:

> server_1  | Unable to connect to SQL database: webgrit_superactivation { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306

this is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  # client
  client:
    image: "ngapp"
    build: "client/dist/."
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
  # Server
  server:
    image: "exapp"
    build: "server/."
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
  # MySQL
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --user=root
    volumes: 
      - ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydbname
```

in the mysql image I use a `data.sql` dump file to init my db, but something is wrong

this is my server container `dbconfig.js` file that I use to connect with mysql db:

```
CONFIG.db_name = process.env.DB_NAME_DEV || "mydbname";
CONFIG.db_user = process.env.DB_USER_DEV || "myuser";
CONFIG.db_password = process.env.DB_PASSWORD_DEV || "mypass";
CONFIG.db_dialect = process.env.DB_DIALECT_DEV || "mysql";
CONFIG.db_host = process.env.DB_HOST_DEV || "localhost";
CONFIG.db_port = process.env.DB_PORT_DEV || "3306";
```

and this is the start of my `data.sql` dump file:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydbname` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `mydbname`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
...
```

Edit: here you can find an error log: https://github.com/ufollettu/SEANSA/blob/master/docker%20error%20log.log

I'm pretty new to docker, how can I solve this problem? 
thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Change host to DB service name i.e `db` -

`CONFIG.db_host = process.env.DB_HOST_DEV || "db";`

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't works. It seems there's an error in the db initialization. I added a error log in my question.